# Can I install Ubuntu 20.04 on a system running Intel Alder Lake architecture

Tags: intel, cpu, motherboard, cpu-architecture

Intel Alder Lake has a new power + efficiency core architecture. As I understand it, the Linux Kernel does not currently support it.

Could I still run Ubuntu LTS on this hardware. What would the implications be? Would the OS treat all cores the same or would the efficiency cores sit idle?

Comment: The Ubuntu Desktop installer has a "Try Ubuntu" environment precisely so that you can test hardware compatibility and conclusively answer these kinds of questions yourself risk-free.

Comment: Isn't the issue that the kernel doesn't yet take advantage of the potential benefits of the power + efficiency core architecture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @C.S.Cameron so feel free to edit it. It's community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and I do run Ubuntu 20.04 on my Alder Lake system. As the kernel is unaware of the hybrid cores it does not run as fast as it can.  But as soon as they have a kernel that does, I will upgrade mine to that kernel and re-run the benchmarks.

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               damien@development 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Z690 UD DDR4 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.4.0-91-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 41 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 4193 (dpkg), 16 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 2560x1440, 2560x1440 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: Cinnamon 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter (Muffin) 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: (Default) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: gnome [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: terminator 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: 12th Gen Intel i9-12900KF(24)  
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 9739MiB / 31953MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```